# Como hacer que el for de python funcione igual que en c++

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x

## codigo python

```python
nx = 5
ny = 2
a=[[0]*nx]*ny
for x in range(0, ny):
    for y in range(0, nx):
        a[x][y]=x * nx + y
        print(x * nx + y)
print("===========")
for x in range(0, ny):
    for y in range(0, nx):
        print(a[x][y])
```

## codigo c++

```c++
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  const int nx=5;
  const int ny=2;
  double a [ny][nx];

  for(int x=0; x<ny ; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<nx ; y++)
    {
      a[x][y]=x*nx+y;
      cout << x*nx+y << endl;
    }
  }
  cout << "=============" << endl;
  for(int x=0; x<ny ; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<nx ; y++)
    {
      cout << a[x][y] << endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;

}
```

¿Por qué no hacen lo mismo?

Comment: En python3.5, por que en python2.7 si funciona

Answer (score 3):

Es un error al inicializar la lista. En Python cuando se hace:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
```

`b` no es una verdadera copia de `a`, sino que contiene la misma lista literalmente, lo que se ha hecho es pasarle la referencia del objeto `a` a `b`. Si modificamos ahora `b`, los cambios también se producen en `a`:

```
b[0] = 8
print(a[0])
>>> 8
```

Esto mismo es lo que esta pasandote a ti, cuando inicializas la lista (matriz) y la llenas de ceros haces esto:

```
a=[[0]*nx]*ny
```

Que para tu ejemplo es:

```
a=[[0]*5]*2
```

ó algo más desarrollado:

```
a=[[0,0,0,0,0]]*2
```

Aquí está el problema, pareciera que estamos creando dos listas **distintas** dentro de `a` pero realmente lo que está pasando es que se han creado dos listas con la misma referencia como pasaba antes, las dos listas anidadas son la misma en memoria. Cuando en el ciclo se modifica la segunda (y = 1),  la primera (que en realidad es la misma) también se modifica por lo que la salida es:

> [[5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]

La solución es inicializar la lista usando un for:

```
a = []
for _ in range(ny):
    a.append([0]*nx)
```

No obstante queda mejor y más eficiente usando List Comprehensions:

```
nx = 5
ny = 2

a=[[0]*nx for _ in range(ny)]
for x in range(0, ny):
    for y in range(0, nx):
        a[x][y]=x * nx + y
        print(x * nx + y)
print("===========")
for x in range(0, ny):
    for y in range(0, nx):
        print(a[x][y])
```

Podemos comprobar que ocuerre en ambos casos imprimiendo las direccioes de memoria de ambas sublista (filas de la matriz):

```
nx = 5
ny = 2

a=[[0]*nx]*ny
print('Lista a:')
print(hex(id(a[0])))
print(hex(id(a[1])))
print(a[0] is a[1])


b=[[0]*nx for _ in range(ny)]
print('\nLista b:')
print(hex(id(b[0])))
print(hex(id(b[1])))
print(b[0] is b[1])
```

Esto nos retorna algo como:

> Lista a:
> 0x232daa5b508
> 0x232daa5b508
> True
>
> Lista b:
> 0x232dce65d48
> 0x232dce54648
> False

Vemos como en el primer caso ambas sublistas son el mismo objeto en memoria pero esto no ocurre en el segundo caso.